# EOFerror with python inputs in ATOM

Tags: python, input, atom-editor

I'm kinda new to programming and just got through an online class, and when I installed atom and tried to make a simple input, it replied with

```
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

for the first line. I booted up python and ran an input and it worked smoothly. The version of python i'm using for atom is 3.6.4.

Here's the code:

```
applicant = input("Enter the applicant's name: ")
interviewer = input("Enter the interviewer's name: ")
time = input("Enter the appointment time: ")
print(interviewer, "will interview", applicant, "at", time)
```

(I copied from somewhere as a test)

Comment: By default Atom cannot run any code, so it would be helpful to know how you run it, e.g. using a script runner or a terminal package.

Comment: Did you load the script extension or the run-python-run extension?

Comment: does your file end with .py?